# Code coverage does not reach class declaration

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, code-coverage

Is there any way to get the code coverage to cover the class declaration of a class like so?

```
public class MyClass{

    public static void foo(int bar){
        System.out.println("The Number is: "+bar);
    }
}
```

I can easily hit the foo method with JUnit testing, but the MyClass declaration stays red. Is this because the class itself has no constructor? And if so, is there any way to cover that bit of code, without changing the code of the class itself?

Thanks

Comment: Unrelated, but is the class meant to be instantiated? If not, it should probably have a private constructor.

Comment: Code coverage tells you what is *executed*.   Declarations are not executable code.

Comment: Take this with a grain of salt:  from a guy that worked at a shop that enforced code coverage requirements for a time, know that they are silly for reasons of your coverage tool wanting to suddenly pick up the class *declaration*.

Comment: So, one *might* mark the "class" line as executed as a poor substitute for marking the invisible default constructor.  But that's an art choice and it hardly matters in practice, since default constructors don't do anything and there isn't a lot you can do to usefully test them.      I've also met shops that want the blank lines between classes marked as covered so that file gets 100% coverage in the extreme case.   You get this when you insist on *line* coverage.   If you instead go for branch coverage, you can get 100% coverage without egregiously covering declarations or blank lines.

Comment: @IraBaxter actually, the reason I find myself hunting on StackOverflow today is that I have a case of code coverage saying that I didn't cover a branch, where that line of code was the class declaration. So I guess it can still happen, but I've been looking around to see if anyone else has ever seen it happen.

Comment: @Trejkaz: Many Java "test coverage" tools look at the byte code to discover "branches".  To the extent that the Java compiler generates a byte code branch because of a class declaration, you could get that effect.     Some Java test coverage tools look only at the branches in the Java source code, and thus won't see an byte-code-internal branch, and thus avoid giving a false report.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This may depend on your specific environment.  But I just checked Eclipse/EclEmma and see the behavior you describe.

Remember, the class *does* have a constructor - it's the default constructor.  If you make a test that simply calls `new MyClass()`, it looks like the red mark goes away.

BUT - the preferred approach for a class with only static methods is to mark the class as `final` and create a private constructor.  Of course if you create a private constructor, that will show up as red in the code coverage - because you can't call a private constructor!

Finally though, remember that code coverage is a tool.  I wouldn't get all worked up about a red mark in the viewer.

Comment: It must be really easy to say things like "don't get worked up about a red mark" when you don't have SonarQube forced on you at work, so that red marks now mean your PR doesn't go in.

Answer (score 2):

Your question forces me to give two comments rather than a direct answer:

1. Do not use the `static` key word unless you have a very good reason.

   It is a common misconception that classes used to provide common functionality should have (only) `static` methods. That comes from the habit to call a class with only `static` methods an *utility classes*.

   Such *all static* utility classes will make your code hard to extend and hard to reuse. And you throw away one of the most powerfull tools in OOP: *polymorphism*. And your one and only advantage is not needing to write the constructor call...
2. Looking for CodeCoverage is easy since we have tools giving us numbers for that and managers love to judge developers by numbers they produce...

   But much more important is the *requirement coverage*. Unfortunately we have no tools to measure  *requirement coverage*. The only tool we have to reach a 100%  *requirement coverage* is *test/behavior driven developement* (TDD/BDD).

Comment: Point 1 here really depends. Maybe you're writing code entirely in a functional style, in which case having many pure functions in static methods seems perfectly fine to me. You get the reusability still, it's just at a different level.

Comment: @ Trejkaz Your view is short term only. What if requirements change and you have to support different versions of a certain method supporting different processing of the data? With your approach you have to change the methods signature to add a selective Parameter **braking existing code** not needing it. If you had no `static` access you could simply use a subclass where needed without the rest even noticing. (Open/Closed Principle)

Comment: generally even if writing in a functional style, I would lump all options into some kind of container (even a hash might be enough), so that you don't have to change the actual method parameters.

Comment: @Trejkaz *"I would lump all options into some kind of container[...], so that you don't have to change the actual method parameters"* **--** That means you never know by looking at the methods signature what parameter in needs. This is **not** the kind of *information hiding* you teachers told you about... ;o)

Comment: You can create the same problem using inheritance just as easily, if you’re making subclasses whose methods require more parameters than the superclass. Ever see a class hierarchy where some subclasses require you to close them and others don’t? ¯\\_( ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Trejkaz in short: when I come along such bad design I improve it.