# What is the meaning of red check mark at class declaration level in Cobertura Maven Plugin report?

Tags: java, junit, code-coverage, cobertura, maven-cobertura-plugin

I have a project with several tests and [Cobertura Maven Plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/). All works fine but one Class with its test are driving me crazy.

This is the cobertura report with 83% of line coverage:

[image: r1]

And this is the basic test:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TimeHelperTest {

  @Test
  public void elapsedMillisToHumanExpression() throws Exception {
    assertEquals("0 min 3 seg 600 millis",
        TimeHelper.elapsedMillisToHumanExpression(1000000000l, 1000003600l));
  }

}
```

## Question

- What means 0 at the left of class name in cobertura report?

Other classes show numbers > 0 and are green.

[image]

## Environment

- java 8
- ubuntu
- eclipse
- pom.xml

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.7</version>
      <configuration>
        <check>
          <haltOnFailure>true</haltOnFailure>
          <branchRate>90</branchRate>
          <lineRate>90</lineRate>
          <totalBranchRate>90</totalBranchRate>
          <totalLineRate>90</totalLineRate>
          <packageLineRate>90</packageLineRate>
          <packageBranchRate>90</packageBranchRate>
        </check>
        <formats>
          <format>html</format>
        </formats>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>cobertura-clean-and-check</id>
          <phase>prepare-package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>clean</goal>
            <goal>cobertura</goal>
            <goal>check</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

## Attempts

I tried with several changes in my @Test but report does not change !!

- use `extends TestCase`
- use `@RunWith`
- use **maven-surefire-plugin** including **/*Test.java
- remove thresholds in pom.xml

## Research

- [Cobertura code coverage is 0% when using Maven 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007759/cobertura-code-coverage-is-0-when-using-maven-3)
- https://github.com/cobertura/cobertura/issues/136
- http://cobertura.996293.n3.nabble.com/Cobertura-shows-zero-code-coverage-despite-all-tests-running-td2829.html

  - This talk about base path of test for ant projects but I can't use it in my maven project

Comment: possible duplicate of [Code coverage does not reach class declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46477696/code-coverage-does-not-reach-class-declaration)

Comment: Please give explanations for down votes, I'd like to learn more.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Code coverage does not reach class declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46477696/code-coverage-does-not-reach-class-declaration)

Answer (score 0):

it means default constructor is not tested.maybe, you can add a test method to `new TimeHelper()` for resolve it.